# parametricplot's option Plotstyle doesn't work if applied to set of curves

Tags: plotting

I am trying to  plot a set of concentric  green dashed circles and a green  ray.

I was able to produce the desired result using `ContourPlot`

```
  b = Range[4, 10, 2]; 

Animate[Show[
      ContourPlot[{x^2 + y^2 == b^2, y = a x}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10},
        Axes -> True, 
       ContourStyle -> {Directive[Lighter[Green], Dashed], Darker[Green]},
        PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], 
      ParametricPlot[{a Cos[\[Theta]], a Sin[\[Theta]]}, {a, 0, 10}, 
       PlotStyle -> Darker@Green]], {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi], 0.01}]
```

but then I read on the wolfram guide that I should use `ParametricPlot` to plot the curves so I tried using it but no matter what i do  PlotStyle does not  change the  color of the circles

```
b = Range[4, 10, 2]
{4, 6, 8, 10}
ParametricPlot[{{# Cos[\[Theta]], # Sin[\[Theta]]} & /@ b, {f Cos[0], 
   f Sin[0]}}, {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {f, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Green,
  Axes -> False]
```

mathematica keeps plotting them blue

what can i do to fix this behavior?

Comment: You don't really need `ParametricPlot[]` for this simple case: `Graphics[{Green, Circle[{0, 0}, #] & /@ Range[4, 10, 2], Line[{{0, 0}, {10, 0}}]}]`

Comment: yes you are right but i had never used parametricplot before so i thought to explore this function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blue (and gold) you see is the boundary of the (empty) areas plotted. (They are indeed areas, i.e., composed of polygons, because you have two parameters `θ` and `f`.) So to color the boundary of the areas, too, use `BoundaryStyle -> Green`.

```
ParametricPlot[
 {{# Cos[θ], # Sin[θ]} & /@ b, {f Cos[0], f Sin[0]}},
 {θ, 0, 2 π}, {f, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Green, 
 Axes -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ParametricPlot[
 {{# Cos[θ], # Sin[θ]} & /@ b, {f Cos[0], f Sin[0]}},
 {θ, 0, 2 π}, {f, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Green, 
 BoundaryStyle -> Green, Axes -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But maybe you want something more like this:

```
Show[
 ParametricPlot[
  {# Cos[θ], # Sin[θ]} & /@ b,
  {θ, 0, 2 π}, PlotStyle -> Green, Axes -> False],
 ParametricPlot[
  {f Cos[0], f Sin[0]},
  {f, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Green]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I'm not sure why the frame disappears, but if you want it, add the option `Frame -> True` to either the first plot or to `Show[]`.

Or if you just want this specific figure, you could do it the way @J.M. suggests in a comment above.

Comment: every once in a while (usually when i don't want to study theory) i make simple gifs with mathematica. it helps me to remember the syntax and the commands. With the figure posted above and a dark background i made a simple animation  of a radar, i would like to add the glowing green effect but i think  i need to learn more  before being able to do this kind of stuff

Comment: The glowing effect is not easy.  See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20855/how-can-i-make-points-glow for instance.