# Glowing weighted graph (network): vertices and edges

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, visualization

I am trying to find a way (desirably simple and performance/speed optimized for larger graphs) to do the following :

- Styling graph vertexes by glow-effect and its intensity depending on `VertexWeight`
- Styling graph edges by glow-effect and its intensity depending on `EdgeWeight`
- `DirectedEdge` glow-effect styling is desirable too (while for simplicity things can start at `UndirectedEdge`)

For example for something like this:

```
RandomGraph[{20,100},
VertexWeight->RandomReal[1,20],
EdgeWeight->RandomReal[1,100],
Background->Black,
BaseStyle->White]
```

i am looking for a visual similar to this one below, except that edges need to glow too:

[image]

The issues that I am experiencing.

#### 1. Simple implementation of a stunning glow

I've seen various glow effects (including [THIS](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20855/13) about glowing points) but not an expert on best visual vs performance ideas. Surprisingly also I have not seen much about glowing lines around. I'd naively start with something like this, but that's probably can be improved visually and performance-wise:

```
bsc=BSplineCurve[{{0,0},{1,1},{2,0}}];
Graphics[
    Table[{White,Opacity[1/k^1.2],Thickness[.005k],CapForm["Round"],bsc},{k,20}],
Background->Black]
```

[image]

#### 2. Passing weights to glow

While I am aware of `VertexShapeFunction` and `EdgeShapeFunction`, I am not quite sure how to optimally pass the weights to them... and if these properties are the right approach.

#### Glow in built-in functions

I've noticed that these functions produces some glow:

```
ComplexPlot[z^2+1,{z,-2-2I,2+2I},ColorFunction->"CyclicReImLogAbs"]
```

[image]

And as noticed by @E.C. in his answer below something like

```
ImageAdjust[DistanceTransform[Graphics[Point[RandomReal[1,{100,2}]]]]]
```

[image]

***Thank you, your help is highly appreciated!***

Comment: The post  [DumpsterDoofus's captivating generative art](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64492/dumpsterdoofuss-captivating-generative-art) comes to mind.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can get an overall glow effect by an `ImageAdd` with a blurred copy of the image mask. Admittedly it's a bit basic, but the effect is compelling. I chose to make a 'brain' network using `AnatomyData` and `NearestNeighbourGraph` to make it look like some over-hyped AI marketing thing:

```
SeedRandom[123];
brain = AnatomyData[Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "Brain"], "MeshRegion"];
boundary = RegionBoundary[brain];
nng = NearestNeighborGraph[RandomPoint[boundary, 1000], 7];
brainnetimg = Rasterize[
   GraphPlot3D[nng, ViewPoint -> Left, 
    VertexStyle -> Directive[AbsolutePointSize[7], White], 
    EdgeStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[2], White], 
    Background -> Black]
   , ImageSize -> 1000];
ImageAdd[ImageAdjust[Blur[Binarize@brainnetimg, 7], .1], 
 ImageMultiply[brainnetimg, 
  LinearGradientImage[{Blue, Cyan, Purple}, 
   ImageDimensions[brainnetimg]]]]
```

[image: img]

To get the weights to affect the size of the glow you'll probably need to use the `EdgeShapeFunction` and `VertexShapeFunction`. I created a billboard texture of
a lens effect with alpha and I used this image for the vertices:

[image: img]

I also used the edge glow effect you mentioned in the question which stacks the lines. Edges with more weight should have more glow, and vertices with more weight will have a larger flare:

```
SeedRandom[123];
G = SpatialGraphDistribution[100, 0.20];
g = RandomGraph[G];
glowtexture = Import["lensbb.png"];
edgeWeights = RandomReal[1, EdgeCount[g]];
vertexWeights = RandomReal[1, VertexCount[g]];

edgeShapeFunc = 
  With[{weight = AnnotationValue[{g, #2}, EdgeWeight]}, 
    Table[{RGBColor[0.7, 1.0, 0.9], Opacity[1/k^1.3], 
      Thickness[.001 k*weight], CapForm["Round"], Line[#1]}, {k, 20}]] &;

vertexShapeFunc = 
  With[{weight = AnnotationValue[{g, #2}, VertexWeight]}, 
    Inset[glowtexture, #1, Center, weight*0.3]] &;

g = Graph[g, EdgeWeight -> edgeWeights, VertexWeight -> vertexWeights,
   VertexShapeFunction -> vertexShapeFunc, Background -> Black, 
  EdgeShapeFunction -> edgeShapeFunc, PlotRangePadding -> .1]
```

[image: img]

Rather than use the line stacking / opacity trick above to produce the glowing edges, you could also use textured polygons instead. This is faster but a disadvantage is when the edges become too thick the caps are visible and ugly:

```
g = Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}}];
edgeWeights = {1, 2, 3}/6.;
vertexWeights = {1, 2, 3}/6.;

glowtexture = Import["lensbb.png"];
edgegradimg = LinearGradientImage[{Transparent,Cyan,Transparent}, {64,64}];

edgeShapeFunc = 
  Module[{weight = AnnotationValue[{g, #2}, EdgeWeight], s = 1/10., 
     vec = #1[[2]] - #1[[1]], perp},
    perp = Cross[vec];
    {Texture[edgegradimg], 
     Polygon[{
         #1[[1]]-perp*weight*s, 
         #1[[1]]+perp*weight*s,
         #1[[2]]+perp*weight*s,
         #1[[2]]-perp*weight*s
     }, VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0,0},{1,0},{1,1},{0,1}}]
    }] &;

vertexShapeFunc = 
  With[{weight = AnnotationValue[{g, #2}, VertexWeight]}, 
    Inset[glowtexture, #1, Center, weight*3]] &;

g = Graph[g, EdgeWeight -> edgeWeights, VertexWeight -> vertexWeights,
   VertexShapeFunction -> vertexShapeFunc, Background -> Black, 
  EdgeShapeFunction -> edgeShapeFunc, PlotRangePadding -> .5]
```

[image: glow 2]

Comment: +1 Very beautiful! Do you think edges would benefit from the same approach you are using for vertices? ...some thin glow mask

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov possibly - if I can find out how to texture a line with a perpendicular fade-to-transparency gradient. Unfortunately though Line does not want to accept VertexTextureCoordinates, so maybe one could use a thin oriented cuboid, polygon, or parallelogram for the edges instead which would allow texturing.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov updated - it turns out it wasn't too hard to do with polygon after all.

Comment: Wow, impressive, thank you !

Comment: This seems to be some picture from the Mathematica documentation for `GradientFilter` section properties and relations with the built-in RemoveBackground applied. Maybe there is some noise added. It is almost monochrome with this turquoise color. This may lead to a personal concept, how to make the glow and adapt the colors.

Answer (score 9):

`DistanceTransform` gives us a distance map of the type that we need for glow.

First we define the light source:

```
bg = ConstantImage[White, 200];
line = HighlightImage[
  bg, {
   Black,
   Thick,
   Line[{{50, 100}, {150, 100}}]
   }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Next, we compute the distance transform. We scale it such that 1 in the resulting image corresponds to the diagonal of the image.

```
glow = ColorNegate@Image[Divide[
     ImageData@DistanceTransform[line],
     200 Sqrt[2]
     ]^0.2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The number 0.2 controls how quickly the glow dies off.

Next, we can apply a color to the glow:

```
glow ConstantImage[Red, 200]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And we can even apply color functions:

```
ImageApply[List @@ ColorData["AvocadoColors", #] &, glow]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Creating a nice color function will be key to create a nice glow like the one in your example.

Creating a glowing graph is quite straight-forward using this technique. Every edge is a line and every vertex is a point or a disk. In the end, we can put them together into one image.

I'll leave it to the reader to create a robust function for this. I will just make a small example.

We'll use the Pappus graph for the example:

```
embedding = First@GraphData["PappusGraph", "Embeddings"];
coords = List @@@ GraphData["PappusGraph", "Edges"] /. Thread[
    Range[Length[embedding]] -> embedding
    ];
Graphics[{
  Point[embedding],
  Line[coords]
  }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Drawing it onto an image instead of in a graphics requires rescaling the coordinates:

```
toImageCoordinates[{x_, y_}] := {
  Rescale[x, {-1, 1}, {0, 200}],
  Rescale[y, {-1, 1}, {0, 200}]
  }

primitives = Join[
   Point@*toImageCoordinates /@ embedding,
   Line@*toImageCoordinates /@ coords
   ];
```

This function will draw any primitive with a glow:

```
draw[primitive_, size_, glow_] := Module[{bg, img},
  bg = ConstantImage[White, 200];
  img = HighlightImage[bg, {
     Black,
     PointSize[Large],
     Thick,
     primitive
     }];
  ColorNegate@Image[Divide[
      ImageData@DistanceTransform[img],
      size Sqrt[2]
      ]^glow]
  ]

draw[First@primitives, 200, 0.2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now the plan is to map this function over all primitives.

```
images = draw[#, 200, 0.2] & /@ primitives;
ImageAdd @@ images // ImageAdjust
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is obvious from this that edges and points can have different amounts of glow. Because of time constraints, I will not make the function that puts all this together into a "glowing graph" function, but I leave this here as a possible approach to solving this problem.

Comment: This is very beautiful, and a neat approach, but here glow intensity does not the depend on `VertexWeight` and `EdgeWeight`  for a particular vertex or edge right? Those are essential requirements.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov I didn’t have time to make more examples, but this approach is very flexible. As you can see, we create one mask for each primitive, i.e. each edge and each vertex. Each of those masks can have their own values for how much they should glow.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting approach +1 :-) Thank you for your efforts!

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Due to time constraints, I am not going to be able to build an automated solution for the problem, but I fleshed out my description of how it can be done with `DistanceTransform` a bit.

Comment: thank you very much - what you did already helps a lot.

Comment: Really nice solution that I tryed to implement it to gnerate a glowing star. But it seems that the code has a bug when excuted on version 12. There is an artifact at the top of the image. A totally white row is generated at the top (the first row of pixels).  It seems it is a bug before 'DistanceTranform', right at the line of 'HighlightImage'. Does anyone know how to solve this bug? Or is is only happen on my laptop?