# How can I style a Line like "Glassrectangle"?

Tags: plotting

[image: Glassrectangle I i]

I'd like a thick Line to look like ChartElementFunction -> "GlassRectangle"

How can that be accomplished?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using `ParametricPlot` with a custom `ColorFunction`:

```
ClearAll[parametricCurve, glassGradientCF]
parametricCurve[curve_, width_][x_, u_] := curve[x] + 
    (1 - 2 u) width/2 Cross @ Normalize[curve'[x]];

glassGradientCF[color_: Red] :=  Module[{}, BarChart[{1}]; 
   System`BarFunctionDump`GlassGradient[color] @ #4]&;
```

***Examples:***

```
c1[x_] := {x + 1, 2 x}

pp1 = ParametricPlot[parametricCurve[c1, 1][x, u], {x, 1, 4}, {u, 0, 1}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> Red, ColorFunction -> glassGradientCF[], Axes -> False]
```

[image]

```
c2[x_] := {x, Sin[x] + x/2}
pp2 = ParametricPlot[parametricCurve[c2, .5][x, u], {x, 0, 3 Pi}, {u, 0, 1},
  BoundaryStyle -> Green, ColorFunction -> glassGradientCF[Green],  Axes -> False]
```

[image]

```
c3[x_] := 3 {Cos @ x + 2, Sin @ x + 2}
pp3 = ParametricPlot[parametricCurve[c3, -.5][x, u], {x, 0, 3 Pi/2}, {u, 0, 1}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> Blue, ColorFunction -> glassGradientCF[Blue], Axes -> False]
```

[image]

```
Show[pp1, pp2, pp3, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: One question though - the edges of the curved lines show little 'teeth'  
What is the best way to get a clean edge?

Comment: I'm using Mathematica 12.2 on Mac - I'm receiving an error msg:
Blend::arg: {System`BarFunctionDump`GlassGradient[][0],System`BarFunctionDump`GlassGradient[][1/19],System`BarFunctionDump`GlassGradient[]
...
[8/19],System`BarFunctionDump`GlassGradient[][9/19],<<10>>} is not a valid list of colors or images, or pairs of a real number and a color or an image.

Comment: One typo found. Instead of 
c2[x_] := 3 {Cos @ x + 2, Sin @ x + 2}
it should read
c3[x_] := 3 {Cos @ x + 2, Sin @ x + 2}

Comment: @Gannicus, corrected the typo. Modified version of `glassGradientCF`  works in v12.2.

Comment: Thanks very much, it works now. Takes on a Macbook Pro 2.7GHz almost 2 minutes to run.
Probably of the hi res. The teeth are pretty much gone, definitely much less than in the pics above

One more question: How do you possibly know about 'GlassGradient'  ?

Wolfram comes up empty, ditto for Google (which already finds this contribution)

Comment: @Gannicus, internal chart element functions are not documented. The way I found about `GlassGradient` is thru a spelunking expedition: Used `ClearAttributes[ChartElementDataFunction, {Protected, ReadProtected}];
?? ChartElementDataFunction` to discover that we can get the internal function that constructs the graphics primitives using `ChartElementData["GlassRectangle", "InternalChartElementFunction"]`  (which gives ``System`BarFunctionDump`GlassGradientBar``). Then ``??System`BarFunctionDump`GlassGradientBar`` reveals that this function calls  ...

Comment: ... ``System`BarFunctionDump`GradientBar`` which in turn calls ``System`BarFunctionDump`GlassGradient`` to construct a color function that gives the _glass_ look/feel.

Answer (score 10):

Borrowing from the technique in the [glowing edges answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/228763/72682), you can create polygons and texture them with any image:

```
texturedLine[p1_, p2_, teximg_, width_] := 
  Module[{s = width, vec = p2 - p1, perp}, perp = Cross[vec];
   {Texture[teximg], 
    Polygon[{p1 - perp*s, p1 + perp*s, p2 + perp*s, p2 - perp*s}, 
     VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}];

glassTex = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6vZR.png"];
glassTex = ImageTake[glassTex, {20, 30}, {15, -15}];

Graphics[{
  (* create a line from 0,0 to 1,1 with thickness .05 *)
  texturedLine[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, glassTex, .05],

  (* create lots of lines around a circle *)
  texturedLine[#[[1]], #[[2]], glassTex, .3] & /@ 
   Partition[CirclePoints[50], 2, 1]
  }]
```

[image: glass textured lines]

Comment: Excellent, thanks much!

Comment: Flinty - when I reduce Circlepoints to say 10, it becomes visible that it's a bunch of rectangles (which is what I asked for  )

Is there an easy way to map such a rectangle to a sector of a circle. Or to a segment of a ring when mapping to a function such as sin x?