# Applying a ColorFunction across the width of a line

Tags: plotting, graphics, color

I would like to apply a `ColorFunction` across the width of the line so that the line remains bright white at the center and fades to background color shortly thereafter at the edges creating the look of an oscilloscope trace (or at least, that's what I think it will result in). (something similar to [this](https://www.alamy.com/oscilloscope-trace-view-of-a-cathode-ray-oscilloscope-cro-screen-displaying-a-sinusoidal-voltage-against-time-trace-a-cro-is-an-item-of-electronic-image335446986.html))

```
Plot[x, {x, -1, 1}
 , PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.04], White}
 , Background -> Darker@Cyan
 ]
```

[image]

From what I understand, the `ColorFunction` works along the length of the line as follows;

```
Plot[x, {x, -1, 1}
 , PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.04], White}
 , Background -> Darker@Cyan
 , ColorFunction -> Hue
 ]
```

[image]

Thanks in advance for your replies and suggestions.

Comment: Something like `ColorFunction -> (Opacity[#1, White] &)` and removing the `White` from the `PlotStyle`?

Comment: `Plot[Sin[x], {x, -4, 4}, PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.04]}, 
 ColorFunction -> (Opacity[#1, White] &), Background -> Darker@Cyan]` results in a gradient in the x-direction shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8cfh.png).

Comment: I've posted a modified color function with a nonlinear dependence on the horizontal value in the answer below; is that along the lines of what you were thinking? It kinda looks like a fading trace on a phosphor screen to me. I guess I am not sure why it should be fading in both directions, but maybe I am misunderstanding what you want to achieve.

Comment: Like an oscilloscope trace, bright along the center of the trace and fading width wise as it goes across the screen. (something similar to [this](https://www.alamy.com/oscilloscope-trace-view-of-a-cathode-ray-oscilloscope-cro-screen-displaying-a-sinusoidal-voltage-against-time-trace-a-cro-is-an-item-of-electronic-image335446986.html)).

Comment: maybe `ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Darker@Cyan, White, Darker@Cyan}, #] &)`?

Comment: For glowing lines you could have a look at this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/228763/72682

Comment: @kglr : It is brighter at the center of the screen as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88i1m.png). Please see my comment above yours for the picture of a trace.

Comment: something like `ParametricPlot[{x, 1 - t + x}, {x, -1, 1}, {t, -.1, .1}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> None, Background -> Darker@Cyan, 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Darker@Cyan, White, 
      Darker@Cyan}, (#4 + .1)/.2] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/2]`?

Comment: @kglr : This looks ok. How do I adapt it for `Plot`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible to make textured lines [like in this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/246049/72682) and you could use the linear gradient texture from my other answer on [glowing graph edges](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/228763/72682). However, if you need curves, a lot of textured lines (actually polygons) will have gaps and it looks bad.

For something like a scope trace for curves, as mentioned in the comments, it might be better to go with a `DensityPlot` like this:

```
plot = Plot[Sin[8.3 x] + 0.5 Cos[4. x], {x, 0, 3}];
line = Cases[plot, Line[_], Infinity] // First;
reg = SignedRegionDistance[line];
DensityPlot[Quiet@Exp[-reg[{x, y}]^2/0.002], {x, 0, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50, ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors"]
```

[image]

A better `ColorFunction` and some axes can make it look more scope-y

```
cols = {{0., Darker[Green, .8]}, {0.7, Darker[Green, .4]}, {0.85, Green}, {1, White}};
DensityPlot[Quiet@Exp[-reg[{x, y}]^2/0.004], {x, 0, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50, 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[cols, #1] &), GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Using a slight modification of [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/246057/125):

```
ClearAll[pCurve]
pCurve[f_, width_: 1/2][x_, u_] := {x, f@x} + (1-2 u) width/2 Cross@Normalize[{1, f'@x}]

colorFunc[color_: Red] := Blend[{color, White, color}, #4] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
f1[x_] := x

f2 = # Sin@# &;

color = Darker@Cyan;

ParametricPlot[pCurve[f1][x, t], {x, -3, 3}, {t, 0, 1}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> color, Background -> color, 
 ColorFunction -> colorFunc[color], Frame -> False, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

```
ParametricPlot[pCurve[f2, 1][x, t], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {t, 0, 1}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> color, Background -> color, 
 ColorFunction -> colorFunc[color], Frame -> False, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
Plot[x,
  {x, -1, 1},
  PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.04],
  Background -> Darker@Cyan,
  ColorFunction -> (Opacity[4 (#1 - #1^2), White] &)
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Using `Haloing[]`:** (introduced with v13.3)

```
Framed[#
,Background->GrayLevel[0.5]
,RoundingRadius->10
,FrameMargins->5
]&@Framed[#
,Background->GrayLevel[0.75]
,RoundingRadius->5
,FrameMargins->5
]&@
Plot[{Sin[8.3 x] + 0.5 Cos[4. x]}
, {x, 0, 3}
,Axes->False
, PlotStyle -> {White,Haloing[Lighter@Cyan,1,4]}
,Background->Blend[{Cyan,Gray}]
,Frame->True
,GridLines->Automatic
,GridLinesStyle->{{Black,Dotted},{Black,Dotted}}
,Method->{"GridLinesInFront"->True}
,ImageMargins->{{10,20},{10,20}}
]
```

---

[image]